# What is the best way to store dates using Neo4j graph database?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am currently working on a graph database where every node has a start date and an end date. I am using a structure that was recommended by neo4j, [where day, month and year all are stored as separate nodes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evOiT.png) So all the nodes in my graph are connected with the day node through a `:Start_Date` and `:End_Date relationship`. The graph consists of a lot of nodes that are connected to the day node, that is why we decided to store the day, month and year as a separate nodes. Our query would now look like

```
MATCH (a:something)-[:StartDate]->(d:Date_Day), (a)-[:EndDate]->(c:Date_Day)
MATCH (d)-[:In_Month]->(m:Date_Month)-[:In_Year]->(y:Date_Year), (c)-[:In_Month]->(m1:Date_Month)-[:In_Year]->(y1:Date_Year)
```

and it would return [the following table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26hAy.png). Is there a way to return this as a date or to query on a date? We would also like to add a timestamp in order to store when a node was mutated. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why dont ypu just use datetime format?

Comment: How do you mean? like storing the datetime as a attribute in every node?

Comment: Yes, exactly whar i mean

Comment: But then every node has to be checked on that attribute, would that not make the database very slow?

Comment: Not if it's indexed properly